# Intellij Idea dont detect local changes of non code files

Tags: intellij-idea

I cloned the my repo from github using Idea and i have modified some sources files and push them into git. But when i modify a file in another folder inside of the project, idea don't detect the change and this file is important for the project.

My project structure folder is something like:

-Project_main_folder/

----Game/

--------src/

------------main.java

------------other_java_files

--------libs/

----db/

--------database.sql

And when i modify the database.sql (for example), idea dont detect it changes. How can i make it detect it and upload it to github??

Thanks c:

Comment: You should right-click on the db directory and mark it as a resource directory. Alternatively, adopt a standard directory structure and Intellij will just work without you having to tell it where your source and resources are.

Comment: But the folder is not showed in the project structure of idea

Comment: Have a look at the drop-down at the top of the project panel and see that it's at `project` level.

Comment: It is in the project level, but it isn't showing the others folders :c